# Remove Additive Zero Mean Gaussian Noise

Tags: normal-distribution, noise, white-noise

I have six values, and each value is corrupted by Additive-Zero-Mean-Gaussian Noise with var = 0.05).

Each value is range from 0 to 1. Is there anyway for me to remove these additive noise?